# Integrated Graphics VS GPU Performance

Tags: cpu, gpu, desktop-computer, computer-building, integrated-graphics

I'm building a PC.
I'm using an Intel i7-8700 as my CPU, which has Intel Iris 630 UHD integrated graphics.
I'm getting 16 GBs of RAM.
I have an EVGA GeForce GT 730 2GB dedicated GPU.

Which should I use? The integrated graphics, or the GPU?

I have gaming performance in mind.

Comment: Solitaire is a game, so you'll need to be more specific. Also, the nVidia 730 is a very low-end GPU. It's still likely a little more powerful than the integrated graphics option, but not by much. Neither of these are really "gaming" options. Finally, this question cannot really be answered here because your needs are unique to you, and what works for you may not work for someone else. You are asking us to advise between two hardware options, which is an off-topic request on SuperUser for the above reasons. There are also GPU comparison tools on well-known websites you should check out.

Comment: Get one of the various free GPU benchmarking utilities out there, and try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [User Benchmarks](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GeForce-GT-730-vs-Intel-UHD-Graphics-630-Desktop-Coffee-Lake-i3/m12582vsm359294), the integrated graphics is actually faster! Hope your not trying to do 4K gaming. I tried the 4K on a 3D game (a low end game, not a high powered game) and was getting an unplayable 4-8 fps. The UHD 630 will do OK (not great) at 1080p.